# How to update a branch w/o getting the revert from an earlier, unwanted merge of it to master

Tags: git

From a post by Linus Torvalds [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt), Linus shows a feature branch with A and B commits prematurely merged into origin/master at M, then reverted back at W to restore the Master branch:

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x---W
              /
---------A---B
```

He goes on to show (by what I understand) that if C and D are made to complete the feature, then merging in the feature branch will lose the A and B changes because Master gets rid of them at W.

So he suggests to revert the revert to get:

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x---W---x----Y
              /
---------A---B---C---D
```

where Y is the revert of W, then merge in the feature branch.

Now this is all good - it makes sense.

I'm however not ready to put the feature branch into Master. I do though wish the latest master changes so merge those into my feature branch.

But then my feature branch is also getting the W revert, undoing A and B in it.

If I revert the revert at Y the merge into my branch, then I suspect my feature branch will be ok, but then Master will have my feature in it which I don't wish yet.

How do I update from master without getting the revert at W?

Comment: Why would your feature should know nothing about the merge to master. It should have all the master commits up to the branch point only right? Why does it know about the o's?

Comment: I think you're right - I got confused. I'll edit.

Comment: Your feature branch is not affected by the merge.

Comment: I thought about why the branch was affected and it was because I merged Master into it - I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of [Torvalds' Howto](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) he recommends

> ```
> $ git checkout E
> $ git rebase --no-ff P
> ```
>
> yielding
>
> ```
>    A'---B'---C'------------D'---E'  <-- recreated topic branch
>   /
>  P---o---o---M---x---x---W---x
>   \         /
>    A---B---C----------------D---E
> ```

To determine ***best common ancestor*** to rebase on (P), you can use `git merge-base M~ E`. After that you are ok to merge master to feature or vice-versa